# How to get users input from ngx-timepicker-field

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

I am new to angular and currently using v7 
I am trying to change the default time of a  `ngx-timepicker-field` 
when the user types in new time since the time is entered via keyboard and not with the clock face

```
<!-- removed classes to reduce the need to scroll/>
<div formArrayName="operatingTimes">
    <div [formGroupName]="Monday">
       <div >
           <mat-checkbox formControlName="isOpen">Monday
           </mat-checkbox>
       </div>
       <div >
            <ngx-timepicker-field [format]="24" defaultTime="08:00" formControlName="openTime">
            </ngx-timepicker-field>
       </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

so my question is how is the users input registered and how does one retrieve the inputted value from what the user entered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the eventEmitter `timeChanged` to get new data when times change manually by user input :

HTML :

```
<ngx-timepicker-field [format]="24" defaultTime="08:00" (timeChanged)="onChangeHour($event)">  </ngx-timepicker-field>
```

TS :

```
  onChangeHour(event){
    console.log(event);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to set a local reference to the html element:

```
  <ngx-timepicker-field [format]="24" defaultTime="08:00" formControlName="openTime" #openTime>
```

Then in your corresponding typescript file, you can access the selected time as follows:

```
@ViewChild('openTime') openTime: NgxTimepickerFieldComponent;

public myMethod(): void {
   console.debug(this.openTime.timePickerTime); // Output current selected time here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Agranom/ngx-material-timepicker/blob/master/README.md 
i saw that the  `ngx-timepicker-field` component has a property timeChanged which emits the time that was entered by the user

Comment: Can you share an example for easy understanding?

Answer (score 0):

For reactive forms, bind form control variable:
.html file:

```
 <ngx-timepicker-field
             [minutesGap]="15"
             formControlName="startTime"></ngx-timepicker-field>
```

.ts file:

```
 startTime: new FormControl('9:00 am', [Validators.required])
```